# Stateful processing in Apache Beam with key-value states

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stateful

I am trying to implement a stateful process with Apache Beam. I've gone through both Kenneth Knowles articles ([Stateful processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) and [Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/)), but I didn't find a solution to my issue. I am using the Python SDK.

In particular, I am trying to have a stateful DoFn that contains key-value objects and I need to add new elements and sometimes remove some.

I saw [a solution may be to use a SetStateSpec](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/userstate.html#SetStateSpec) with [Tuple coder](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/40326dd0a2a1c9b5dcbbcd6486a43e3875a64a43/sdks/python/apache_beam/coders/coders.py#L999) inside my DoFn class. The problem is that the SetSpaceSpec has no option for a 'pop'-like function. It seems to me that the only way to delete elements is to delete them all with `.clear()`.
It looks like you can't specify just an element to erase with this function.

A chance to overcome this problem may be to clear and rewrite state any time I need to delete an element in the state, but this looks inefficient to me.

Do you have any idea on how to do it efficiently?

Python version 3.8.7
apache-beam==2.29.0

Comment: How about using `ReadModifyWriteStateSpec` and have a custom implementation of a coder for a dict for example? Have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/45911664/8330018, it's using a heap, but you can use some ideas from there to have your implementation of `.pop` for example

Comment: Hi @TudorPlugaru, thanks a lot for your answer. Do you have any idea on how to implement a coder using the Python SDK classes? The example you posted uses the Java one and I am not confident with it

Comment: The apache beam repo is a nice resource if you want code examples. Regarding an example of a custom coder, you can find it here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/group_with_coder.py#L50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed @TudorPlugaru's suggestion and I come out with this. Hope it will be useful for someone else.

```
import json
from apache_beam.coders import Coder

class MyDictCoder(Coder):
    """ My custom dictionary coders """
    def encode(self, o):
        return json.dumps(o).encode()

    def decode(self, o):
        return json.loads(o.decode())

    def is_deterministic(self) -> bool:
        return True
```

In the DoFn declaration

```
from apache_beam.transforms.userstate import ReadModifyWriteStateSpec

class MyDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    DICTSTATE= ReadModifyWriteStateSpec(name='dictstate', coder=MyDictCoder())
    
    def process(self, element, DictState=beam.DoFn.StateParam(DICTSTATE)):
        # Do something
        yield DictState
```

And adding this line inside the pipeline (as done in the [Beam example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/group_with_coder.py#L98))

```
beam.coders.registry.register_coder(typing.Dict, MyDictCoder)
```